# Присвоение переменной значения ячейки sqlite Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Хотелось бы передать значение ячейки переменной, там текстовое значение. Как это можно сделать?

```
self.vib31 = int(input("Введи id: "))
who1 = self.theCursor.execute("SELECT name FROM product WHERE id=(?)", (self.vib31))
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы одно значение получить:

```
[name], = cursor.execute('select name from product where id=?', (some_id,))
```

[Полный пример](https://repl.it/@zed1/unpack-value-sqlite):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute('create table product (id, name)')
db.executemany('insert into product values (?, ?)', [(1,'a'), (2,'b')])
[name], = db.execute('select name from product where id=?', (some_id,))
print(name) # -> a
```

Comment: Разве не хватит просто `name, = `? Зачем оборачивать в скобки?

Comment: @gil9red: вы попробуйте (полный пример представлен) и узнаете.

Comment: Понял, ошибся. Просто, писал уже такой же код, но у курсора вызывал fetchone (`name, = db.execute('select name from product where id=?', (1,)).fetchone()`), и это работало :)

Comment: @gil9red: `fetchone()` не проверяет, что ровно один результат.